# Well-posed ODEv definition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An ODE is well-posed if the solutions vary continuously over the initial conditions. What is the intuitive meaning/requirement for this ?

Comment: It means it satisfies the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem.

Comment: @Nameless No, it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In physical problems you only know the initial data to some degree of precision.  If you didn't have continuous dependence, knowing the initial data to 99.99999% accuracy might give you a completely different solution to the ODE.  Basically, an ODE that isn't well posed isn't a useful model.